# Conflicting $.ajaxSetup for jQuery functions

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two jQuery scripts - One for inline form editing and the second is the jQuery autocomplete.

The autocomplete has the following ajaxSetup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   url: '/notes/inlineedit',
   type: 'POST',
   async: false,
   timeout: 500
});
```

Meanwhile, the autocomplete requires type: TRUE and async: TRUE. Is there a way to set this options to only affect one script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is setting ajax settings *globally* that should only be done **per ajax request**. You can pass all of the same options to the `$.ajax([settings])` function